# Selecting a checkbox based on value with Selenium chromedriver in Python

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

This is the HTML of the checkbox I am trying to interact with:

```
 <th>
                                        <input data-control-element="Vol_Year_Selector" type="checkbox" value="2022">
                                        <Label>2022</Label>
                                    </th>
                                    <th>
                                        <input data-control-element="Vol_Year_Selector" type="checkbox" value="2021">
                                        <Label>2021</Label>
                                    </th>
                                    <th>
                                        <input data-control-element="Vol_Year_Selector" type="checkbox" value="2020">
                                        <Label>2020</Label>
                                    </th>
                                    <th>
                                        <input data-control-element="Vol_Year_Selector" type="checkbox" value="2019">
                                        <Label>2019</Label>
                                    </th>
                                    <th>
                                        <input data-control-element="Vol_Year_Selector" type="checkbox" value="2018">
                                        <Label>2018</Label>
                                    </th>
```

I need to click this checkbox, along with a few other very similar ones. This is the code I have now based on what I was able to find:

```
    driver.find_element(By.XPATH,"//option[@value='"+dl_data+"']").click()
```

where I am iterating through the array dl_data that contains all of the year strings ["2018","2019",....]
This doesn't work, as selenium is finding no such element.

Could anyone tell me what I am doing wrong here?

Comment: maybe the element was not still rendered by selenium. When you click on dynamic elements, you should verify that element exists before you click on it

Comment: Why do you use `//option`?! Obviously it should be `//input`

Comment: @JaSON wow, I can't believe it was just that. tbh this is my first time using chrome driver and that's what I found when browsing through SO trying to find my answer. Thank you though!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are looking for option elements, but these are input elements, therefore try:

```
driver.find_element(By.XPATH,"//input[@value='"+dl_data+"']").click()
```